# Passing entity framework query to view error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, localdb

I just created a database with Entity Framework Code first Approach.

Here is my **modal class**

```
public class MobileProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int p_id { get; set; }
    public string  p_name { get; set; }
    public string  p_description { get; set; }

    public string p_price { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my **DbContext** derived class

```
public class Entities : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<MobileProduct> Mobiles { get; set; }
}
```

I just created a query to pass this data t view on an action method

```
Entities db = new Entities();
public ActionResult Mobiles()
{
    var q = from n in db.Mobiles
            select n;
    return View(q);
}
```

Here is my **View**

```
@model HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mobiles";
}

<h2>Mobiles</h2>
```

I got an **error** when accessing the view:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct'.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you want to send a list of MobileProduct to the view? If so; change your model to

```
@model IEnumerable<HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mobiles";
}

<h2>Mobiles</h2>
```

Currently your model only expects one instance of type MobileProduct whereas your Mobiles action is creating a list of MobileProduct. You will also need to evaluate the query in the action by performing a ToList() on it.

```
public ActionResult Mobiles()
        {
            var q = from n in db.Mobiles
                    select n;
            return View(q.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to evaluate the query to a list first.

Comment: `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery` implements `IEnumerable` so no ned to to `ToList`, but +1 from me anyway as the first part is correct.

Comment: You don't need to evaluate in this specific example, but shouldn't you dispose your context before sending everything back to the view? (Haven't used EF in a while...)

Comment: @DavidG you only don't need to evaluate the DbQuery because the context is not being disposed in the action. Sending a query to a view is only asking for trouble as it depends on a context not being previously disposed. It's not a reliable pattern to use. But technically you're correct; ToList() is not strictly required here.

Comment: @daveL Absolutely, but as you put it in your answer, it would be nice to explain why you did it that way. The first half answers the question well and the second part is good practice.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't realizing your query so you're sending the query itself, not the results of the query, to the View.

```
var q = (from n in db.Mobiles
         select n).ToList();
return View(q);
```

As daveL posted, you also need to change the definition of the model in your view.

```
@model IEnumerable<HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct>
```

Comment: You're second point is correct, but casting to a list is not necessary either way. The chief problem is that the OP is send a enumerable to view that expects a single object. The OP would get the same error by merely casting to a list, and it would work just as well sending the queryable directly to the view with the enumerable model definition.

Comment: Sending a query to a view is, IMO, a very bad idea and I would prefer to not see that pattern repeated. Realize the view and then send the data to prevent potentially expensive operations from being hidden by the view processing the query rather than a collection of DTOs.

Comment: I agree, personally, but that doesn't change the fact that it's not required. It's fine to say you *should* do it this way, but to communicate that it *must* be done this way is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but try defining your model as:

```
@model IQuerable<HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct>
```

If that doesn't work, then perhaps:

```
@model IEnunerable<HomeShopping.Models.MobileProduct>
```

...with your object returned as:

```
View(q.ToList());
```

Answer (score -1):

you are saving a query to q, not the evaluation of the query.  You need a ToList() if you expect multiple results.